# Firing an Application on Machine restart

Tags: c++, mfc

I have an application that checks if a windows service is up and running. This app launches on machine restart and before windows services were instantiated and immediately notifies user saying that the windows service on user machine is not found. but the service starts a bit later.

I am using a C++ MFC application. Is it possible to solve this so that the app will check after all windows services are up and running? and if yes, how

Comment: I don't think there is a way to make sure that service startup finished. I would implement a simple sleep timer (~5-10secs) that is started if the application is launched with a certain parameter that you only add to the startup shortcut of the app.

Comment: Rather than sleeping the app, you should look into using a timer.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that Windows is capable of ensuring that a service is started as requested. Why do you think that you have to build an application to double check?